# Variables se asignan a NULL al usarlas como parametros en función por referencia

Tags: php

Buenas.

Deseo asignar atributos a una clase desde un arreglo que podría o no tener las claves, como en este ejemplo:

```
class ClasePrueba extends Model {
    public function fillWithData(array $data){
        $this->ATRIBUTE1 = $data['data1'];
        $this->ATRIBUTE2 = $data['data2'];
        $this->ATRIBUTE3 = $data['data3'];
        $this->ATRIBUTE4 = $data['data4'];
    }
}
```

pero si no existe la clave `data1` o cualquiera de las otras, entonces tengo un error de acceso a index no definido.

> Notice:  Undefined offset: data1

Podría intentar un codigo como el siguiente

```
$this->ATRIBUTE1 = (isset($data['data1'])? $data['data1']: NULL;
```

Pero me he dado cuenta de que el atributo se crea y queda como NULL. Entonces intento un método "assign" que pase por referencia el atributo del modelo y la referencia al elemento del array que podría o no estar, este es un ejemplo:

```
<?php

$array = array("1" => "PHP");

function assign(&$to, &$data){
    if(isset($data)){
        $to = $data;
    }
}

class a {
}

$testClass = new a;
var_dump(isset($testClass->attribute )); // bool(false)
var_dump($testClass->attribute); // Notice:  Undefined property: a::attribute

assign($testClass->attribute, $array["5"]);

var_dump($testClass->attribute); // NULL
var_dump(is_null($testClass->attribute )); // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($testClass->attribute )); // bool(false)
var_dump($testClass);
```

Entonces cuando llamo al primer `var_dump` el resultado es esperado, la variable `$testClass->attribute` no está definida.

Luego en el segundo intento acceder, pero el interprete PHP me notifica que la variable `$testClass->attribute` no está definida, también como lo esperaba.

Llamo a la función `assing` con el atributo de la clase como parámetro y con `$array["5"]` que es una clave indefinida, por lo tanto nunca se ejecuta la asignación dentro de la función `assign`, y por lo tanto no se crea la propiedad del objeto (en teoría)

Entonces todo explota para mi cuando llamo la tercera vez al `var_dump` y devuelve `NULL`. No comprendo por que me devuelve NULL en las siguientes llamadas en vez de notificar que el atributo en la instancia `$testClass` no está definido. Es como si al atributo le asignara NULL de la siguiente forma:

```
$testClass = new a;
var_dump(isset($testClass->attribute )); // bool(false)

$testClass->attribute = NULL;
var_dump($testClass->attribute); // NULL
```

y el ultimo var_dump() devuelve:

```
object(a)#1 (1) {
    ["attribute"]=>
    NULL<br>
}
```

Entonces es como si mis variables se asignan a NULL al usarlas como parámetros en una función por referencia, en vez de notificar que no están definidas como si usara `unset()`, ya que 'técnicamente' nunca los asigno a NULL.

Esta es mi pregunta: ¿por que sucede esto?

Comment: ¿Versión de Laravel?

Comment: uso desde la 5.1

Comment: Desde Laravel 5 es necesario inyectar una nueva instancia de tu ClasePrueba donde quieras llamar alguno de sus métodos: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31032488 Por otra parte, creo lo que pretendes hacer sería mejor con un query builder (constructor de consultas), https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries Se trata de crear consultas dinámicas.

Comment: Comprendo la inyección de dependencias y como funciona el query builder, pero lo que necesitaba era poblar el modelo con los datos desde un array que no siempre tiene todos los elementos. Me acabo de dar cuenta que se puede con el método [`$flight->fill(['name' => 'Flight 22']);`](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill) intersectando las claves de `$fillable` y el `$request->all()`. Pero aun me queda la duda de los valores NULL, hhe editado la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Si se asigna, pasa, o devuelve una variable no definida por referencia, la variable se creará." ...
Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.whatdo.php

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Sobre tu explosión mental: `$array["5"]` no esta definido, cuando intentas acceder a una variable no definida, en vez de obtener el contenido o referencia de esta, PHP te entrega `null`.

```
echo is_null($array["5"]);
```

Algo que debes considerar, pareciera que esperas que la expresión `$array["5"]` se le entregue a la función y que sea evaluada dentro de esta, pero las expresiones que se pasan por argumentos se deben evaluar antes de ser entregadas a las funciones, por lo mismo, lo que PHP ve, es:

```
assign($testClass->attribute, $array["5"]); // $array["5"] not defined
assign($testClass->attribute, null);
```

> por lo tanto nunca se ejecuta la asignación dentro de la función assign, y por lo tanto no se crea la propiedad del objeto (en teoría)

La asignación si se ejecuta, dentro de `assign`, la variable `$data` esta seteada con el valor null.

Sobre el siguiente `var_dump`:

```
var_dump(isset($testClass->attribute )); // bool(false)
```

De la documentación de `isset`

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Es correcto que `isset($testClass->attribute)` regrese falso.